# How to truncate a BigDecimal without rounding

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal, arithmeticexception

After a series of calculations in my code, I have a `BigDecimal` with value `0.01954`

I then need to multiply this `BigDecimal` by `100` and I wish the calculated value to be `1.95`

I do not wish to perform any rounding up or down, I just want any values beyond two decimal places to be truncated

I tried setting scale to 2, but then I got an `ArithmeticException` saying rounding is necessary. How can I set scale without specifying rounding?

Comment: the `Math.floor(VALUE)` will return a int val, so why not do: `(double)((double)Math.Floor(1.95*100)/(double)100)`

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Use either [RoundingMode.DOWN](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#DOWN) or [RoundingMode.FLOOR](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#FLOOR).

```
BigDecimal newValue = myBigDecimal.setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN);
```

Comment: new BigDecimal(4343.33).setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN) returns 4343.32

Comment: @user666 You are using the constructor that takes a floating point value, which can have rounding errors itself. Use the constructor that takes a `String` instead: `new BigDecimal("4343.33").setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN)`

Comment: that is correct, I tried it and it worked. But what if I have a bigDecimal object already existing? will it be treated like the string?

Comment: @San4musa Not true, you will get x.55. You can try it yourself: `BigDecimal myBigDecimal = new BigDecimal("5.5555555");
    BigDecimal newValue = myBigDecimal.setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN);
    System.out.println(newValue);`

Comment: @GriffeyDog you are right, I messed up with HALF_DOWN , my comment can not be edited to I'm deleting the comment 

"RoundingMode.DOWN will fail if the value is x.5555555 as the truncating value is > 0.5 so it will round to x.56 if you use BigDecimal newValue = myBigDecimal.setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN); "

This statement is true for HALF_DOWN not for DOWN mode.

Answer (score 13):

Use the setScale override that includes RoundingMode:

```
value.setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN);
```

Answer (score 9):

I faced an issue truncating when I was using one BigDecimal to set another. The source could have any value with different decimal values.

```
BigDecimal source = BigDecimal.valueOf(11.23); // could 11 11.2 11.234 11.20 etc
```

In order to truncate and scale this correctly for two decimals, I had to use the string value of the source instead of the BigDecimal or double value.

```
new BigDecimal(source.toPlainString()).setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR))
```

I used this for currency and this always results in values with 2 decimal places.

- 11 -> 11.00
- 11.2 -> 11.20
- 11.234 -> 11.23
- 11.238 -> 11.23
- 11.20 -> 11.20

Comment: 11.238 -> 11.28 ?

Answer (score 1):

> BigDecimal.valueOf(7.777)
> .setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN)
> .stripTrailingZeros()

Result: 7.77

> BigDecimal.valueOf(7.7)
> .setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN)
> .stripTrailingZeros()

Result: 7.7

> BigDecimal.valueOf(77)
> .setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN)
> .stripTrailingZeros()

Result: 77

Answer (score 0):

As far as I tested rounding functions doesnt do the magic.What is a value comes as following amount.

```
BigDecimal val2 = new BigDecimal(45.9);
System.out.println(val2.setScale(2,RoundingMode.DOWN));
```

result;
45.89

Best thing is to cast from sql side or write a util function to multiply by 100 and pass to an Integer, again divide by hundred and pass to a BigDecimal.

In my case I used

```
sql:-  CAST(<VALUE> AS decimal(10,2)).
```

Comment: Your first case fails because you use a double to create the `BigDecimal`. Plus, you use `setScale` to _add_ decimals which is the opposite of what the question asks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, **the accepted answer is wrong**. It states to:

> Use either RoundingMode.DOWN or RoundingMode.FLOOR

However, as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#FLOOR), RoundingMode.FLOOR rounds "towards negative infinity". The behaviour is further described in the documentation, saying that:

> If the result is positive, behave as for RoundingMode.DOWN; **if negative, behave as for RoundingMode.UP**

A simple test to show how that behaviour is not truncating values is the following:

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(-1.009).setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR));
// returns: -1.01, so NOT the truncated value of -1.00
```

The **corrects answer is that you can ONLY use RoundingMode.DOWN**, as it literally states in the documentation that this method:

> Never increments the digit prior to a discarded fraction **(i.e.,
> truncates)**